# Solr bookmark query result containing id

Tags: search, solr, pagination

I have requirement to "bookmark" certain Solr query result containing a document. The query is known and the document id is known as well. The result set would obviously change with time but I was wondering if it is possible to execute a query on the Solr and Solr would return result set with proper offset so that desired document would be present in the paged result set if present.

I would compare it to the requirement to bookmark Google search results on the page where result contains [www.stackoverflow.com/question/1](http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/1)

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to know the page number, or just make sure the result set starts from that entry? Do you need to know the previous page?

Comment: My page size is constant and I am using start and rows parameters so if I would know what index the document has I would be able to calculate page offset. So page number would be fine

Comment: Do you have an explicit sort clause, or are you ordering by score?

Comment: yes I have explicit sort clause.

Comment: In that case - retrieve the document with the id in the bookmark, get the value you're sorting by in that document, and make a query with `fq=[* TO <value>}` - this will return the count of documents before your document (include a unique key field if the sort value isn't unique, so that you're sure that the sort is stable). With the count of documents before your document in the sort result you can calculate the page number (i.e. `floor(<documents before> / <page size>)`).

Comment: Currently my ids are not numbers but I can change it to numbers (there is no strong reason to have them as strings). Thank you very much you have been very helpful. I especially like this solution because I also need to support in memory Lucene and this solution will work there as well.

Comment: As long as they're sortable it'll work fine, but if you have numeric ids indexed as strings the sort will be string based (so 11 will sort before 2) in that case.

Comment: In the past the document ids where not numbers at all so I have always sorted by created_at timestamp so I always had the newest documents on the top. Lately the requirement changed and the ids became generated from database sequence but default sort has not changed to I have not cared about it. So I can fix also indexing to include a proper type for it.